# Why one method work perfectly for one action and do not work for another?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm newbee in rails, so could you explain why method `survey_type` works for this **(attempts/new)**:

```
<h2 class="survey-title">
<%= @survey.name %>
<p><small><%= @attempt.survey.description %></small></p>
</h2>

  <%= form_for(@attempt, url: attempt_scope(@attempt)) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :survey_id, @survey.id %>
<ol class="questions">

    <% if is_multanswer?(@survey.survey_type) %>
    <%= f.fields_for :answers, get_answer_fields(@attempt) do |answer_fields| %>
      <li>
        <% question = answer_fields.object.question %>
        <p class="question"><%= question.text %></p>
        <ul class="options">
          <%= collection_check_boxes('survey_attempt[answers_attributes]', question.id, question.options, :id, :text) do |b| %>
            <li class="checkbox">
              <%= b.label { b.check_box + b.text } %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% end -%>

    <%  else %>
    <%= f.fields_for :answers, get_answer_fields(@attempt) do |answer_fields| %>
      <li>
        <% question = answer_fields.object.question %>
        <p class="question"><%= question.text %></p>
        <ul class="options">
          <%= collection_radio_buttons('survey_attempt[answers_attributes]', question.id, question.options, :id, :text) do |b| %>
            <li class="radio">
              <%= b.label { b.radio_button + b.text } %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% end -%>

<% end %>
</ol>
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end -%>
```

and do not work for this **(attempts/show)**:

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="survey-title">
<%= @attempt.survey.name %>
<p><small><%= @attempt.survey.description %></small></p>
</h2>
<ol class="questions">

    <% if is_multanswer?(@survey.survey_type) %>
    <% @attempt.answers.each do |answer| %>
      <li>
        <p class="question"> <%= answer.question.text %> </p>
        <ul class="options">
          <% answer.question.options.each do |option| %>
            <li class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <%= check_box_tag '', '', the_chosen_one?(answer, option), disabled: true %>
                <% color = get_color_of_option(answer, option) %>
                <span class="<%= color %> <%= the_chosen_one?(answer, option) %>"> <%= option.text %> <%= get_weight(option) %> </span>
              </label>
              <p class="answers-number"> <%= number_of_people_who_also_answered(option.id) %> </p>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% end %>

    <% else %>
    <% @attempt.answers.each do |answer| %>
      <li>
        <p class="question"> <%= answer.question.text %> </p>
        <ul class="options">
          <% answer.question.options.each do |option| %>
            <li class="radio">
              <label>
                <%= radio_button_tag '', '', the_chosen_one?(answer, option), disabled: true %>
                <% color = get_color_of_option(answer, option) %>
                <span class="<%= color %> <%= the_chosen_one?(answer, option) %>"> <%= option.text %> <%= get_weight(option) %> </span>
              </label>
              <p class="answers-number"> <%= number_of_people_who_also_answered(option.id) %> </p>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

here is controllers:

**attempts_controller**

```
class AttemptsController < ApplicationController

helper 'surveys'

before_filter :load_survey, only: [:new, :create]

def index
  @surveys = Survey::Survey.active
end

def show
  @attempt = Survey::Attempt.find_by(id: params[:id])
  render :access_error if current_user.id != @attempt.participant_id
end

def new
  @participant = current_user

  unless @survey.nil?
    @attempt = @survey.attempts.new
    @attempt.answers.build
  end
end

def create
  @attempt = @survey.attempts.new(params_whitelist)
  @attempt.participant = current_user
  if @attempt.valid? && @attempt.save
      correct_options_text = @survey.correct_options.present? ? 'Bellow   are the correct answers marked in green' : ''
    redirect_to attempt_path(@attempt.id), notice: "Thank you for answering #{@survey.name}! #{correct_options_text}"
  else
    build_flash(@attempt)
    @participant = current_user
    render :new
  end
end

def delete_user_attempts
  Survey::Attempt.where(participant_id: params[:user_id], survey_id: params[:survey_id]).destroy_all
  redirect_to new_attempt_path(survey_id: params[:survey_id])
end

private

def load_survey
  @survey = Survey::Survey.find_by(id: params[:survey_id])
end

def params_whitelist
  if params[:survey_attempt]
    params[:survey_attempt][:answers_attributes] = params[:survey_attempt][:answers_attributes].map { |attrs| { question_id: attrs.first, option_id: attrs.last } }
    params.require(:survey_attempt).permit(Survey::Attempt::AccessibleAttributes)
  end
end

def current_user
  view_context.current_user
end
end
```

and **surveys_controller**:

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController

      before_filter :load_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      def index
        type = view_context.get_survey_type(params[:type])
        query = if type then Survey::Survey.where(survey_type: type) else Survey::Survey end
        @surveys = query.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(15)
      end

      def new
        @survey = Survey::Survey.new(survey_type: view_context.get_survey_type(params[:type]))
      end

      def create
        @survey = Survey::Survey.new(params_whitelist)
        if @survey.valid? && @survey.save
          default_redirect
        else
          build_flash(@survey)
          render :new
        end
      end

      def edit
      end

      def show
      end

      def update
        if @survey.update_attributes(params_whitelist)
          default_redirect
        else
          build_flash(@survey)
          render :edit
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @survey.destroy
        default_redirect
      end

      private

      def default_redirect
        redirect_to surveys_path, notice: I18n.t("surveys_controller.#{action_name}")
      end

      def load_survey
        @survey = Survey::Survey.find(params[:id])
      end

      def params_whitelist
        params.require(:survey_survey).permit(Survey::Survey::AccessibleAttributes << :survey_type)
      end

    end
```

and helpers:

```
def get_color_of_option answer, option
        if is_quiz?(answer.question.survey.survey_type)
          if option.correct
            'bg-success'
          elsif the_chosen_one?(answer, option)
            'bg-danger'
          end
        elsif is_score?(answer.question.survey.survey_type)
          get_weight_html_class option
        end
      end

      def get_survey_type survey_type
        get_survey_types[survey_type] || get_survey_types.invert[survey_type]
      end

      def get_survey_types
        { 0 => 'quiz',
          1 => 'score',
          2 => 'poll',
          3 => 'multanswer'
        }
      end

      def is_quiz? something
        something == 0 || something == 'quiz'
      end

      def is_score? something
        something == 1 || something == 'score'
      end

      def is_poll? something
        something == 2 || something == 'poll'
      end
      def is_multanswer? something
        something == 3 || something == 'multanswer'
      end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the error log?

Comment: Where are you setting `@survey` in the "show" path? It looks like it should be `@attempt.survey.survey_type`

Comment: @SimpleLime Ohh, good catch, `show` is not in `before_filter :load_survey, only: [:new, :create]`. I think you should made an answer of it.

Comment: Ah I tried to edit my comment to specifically call that out, but guess I missed the 5 minute window so it's been sitting un-updated here

Comment: @Gerry 

        NoMethodError - undefined method `survey_type' for nil:NilClass:
      app/views/attempts/show.html.erb:9:in         `_app_views_attempts_show_html_erb___2111368530368853614_69864292909460'

Comment: @Gerry, and I've already tried to add `:show`to the `before_filter`, but it shows the same error

Comment: Which urls are used to open `show` and `new`? I assume you are using a link (or links)  in some other form(s); can you show those links?

Comment: @Gerry, I'm using those links only once for `new` and `show`,
I'm using `attempt` (`show`) in attempts_controller in `create` action.
and  `new_attempt` (`new`) in `survey.html.erb` :
 
 `<td> <%= link_to survey.name, new_attempt_path(survey_id: survey.id), class: 'survey-name' %> </td>`

Comment: I see, you just need to add another parameter in create to send the `survey_id`, like so: `redirect_to attempt_path(@attempt.id, survey_id: @survey.id)`; just add this along with @simplelime solution and you should be ok.

Comment: @Gerry, that works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AttemptsController` you have

```
before_filter :load_survey, only: [:new, :create]
```

that sets the `@survey` variable for your `new` action, but doesn't get called for `show`, so that action never gets the variable set.

You can add `:show` into your `:only` conditions

```
before_filter :load_survey, only: [:new, :create, :show]
```

and that should fix things

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I've already tried this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: and it shows the same error in both cases: `NoMethodError - undefined method survey_type' for nil:NilClass:
  app/views/attempts/show.html.erb:9:in _app_views_attempts_show_html_erb___2111368530368853614_69864292909460'
  actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in
`

Comment: Just add `survey_id` to be sent in `redirect_to` within `create` action an this should work (i.e. `redirect_to attempt_path(@attempt.id, survey_id: @survey.id)`)